# Expandable List Adapter for ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to Android. I have created an auto generated list activity for contact example.

I have two things -

```
 ContactListActivity.java
 /** auto generated code /**
```

In `ContactListFragment.java` I have modified this method to set the my list.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*** some code **/
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyContact.Contact>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            contactList));
```

I have not yet modified any xml.

Now I want to display an expandable List instead of simple list. I have written a simple `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
    );
```

But I can not set this adapter successfully by calling

```
setListAdapter(myAdapter)
```

It shows compilation error.

```
android.widget.ListAdapter can not be applied to android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter
```

What changes I have to make for this to be working?

This is my `activity_contact_list.xml`

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/contact_list"
    android:name="com.example.sarvesh.litecontacts.ContactListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".ContactListActivity" tools:layout="@android:layout/expandable_list_content"  />
```

Comment: `It shows compilation error.` which error?

Comment: android.widget.ListAdapter can not be applied to android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

As error:

> android.widget.ListAdapter can not be applied to
>   android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter

means currently extending `ListActivity` in `ContactListActivity` class but passing `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` Adapter object to `setListAdapter` method  which is not valid.

To use Expandable List extend [ExpandableListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html) in `ContactListActivity` class instead of `ListActivity`.

Comment: Also see following example :[Android ExpandableListview Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/)